# Python get character from n element to last included last

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
link_element = """a target="_top" aria-current="false" class="Anchor NavList__Anchor" href="/tr/turnuva-konumu/y%C3%BCksek-oran/101/d%C3%BCnya/240/sk-slavia-prague-rak%C3%B3w-cz%C4%99stochowa-hnk-hajduk-split-villarreal-cf-cfr-cluj-nk-maribor-%C5%A1k-slovan-bratislava-h%C5%A1k-zrinjski-mostar/***180254557458746932***">xxx</a"""

uniqueid = link_element['href'][-18:-1]
```

When i try to get the integer value of the link it returns with bs4 and requests libs 18025455745874693 .It does not include the last char.
How can i get the full integer value of the href  ?

Comment: Change `[-18:-1]` to `[-18:]`. Also, it might be a better idea to split your string by slashes and then get the last element instead of getting the splice of a string with hardcoded indices when you don't know the length of the string. Just made an answer to explain this for you.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can just replace `[-18:-1]` with `[-18:]`. Using `-1` as your ending index excludes the last character.

However, in the case where this ID's length is variable (ie. may not always be 18 characters), the better option would be to split your string by `/` and grab the last element.

```
unique_id = link_element['href'].split("/")[-1]
```